# Why don't my groovy enums work, or even compile?

Tags: groovy, enums

I'm running Groovy Version: 1.7.0 JVM: 1.6.0_17

*(Update -- I just upgraded to 1.7.1 and get the same errors!)*

I've tried to use enums, using the exact syntax from the groovy documentation, and each time I see the compile error:

```
Groovy:The class java.lang.Enum refers to the class java.lang.Enum and uses 1 parameters, but the referred class takes no parameters
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

For example: This code won't compile or run, and gets the error above.

```
enum VehicleStatus { OFF, IDLING, ACCELERATING, DECELARATING }

class Vehicle
{
    Long id
    Long version
    VehicleStatus status
}
```

Comment: BTW: I've noticed similar errors reported several years ago, on groovy 1.5 JetGroovy, but not recently, c.f., http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/GRVY-1044

Comment: post the offending code please

Comment: I have the same issue, but only in netbeans. Using the Enum in a Grails project or just using groovyc to compile does not show the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an error with the Netbeans IDE: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189275

I've found that, after running Clean, the error persists in the editor, but does not actually cause a problem at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

See http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/79003

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this. I receive the same error as you if the only code in the script is the same as yours. However, it goes away once you add the line

```
def a = new Vehicle(id: 1, version: 0, status: VehicleStatus.IDLING)
```

I'm using Groovy 1.7.1 as well and executing the script from within Netbeans 6.8.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't solve the mystery, but at least I have a workaround. I wonder if it's a netbeans problem, as I'm using netbeans, too.

Comment: @ ראובן - It doesn't even need to be that particular line. Simply adding an assert() outside of the class has the same result. Unfortunately, I haven't used Groovy enough to know why that is.